# Dspace JSPUI statistics not show values

Tags: statistics, dspace

I just installed Dspace 4.2. I added some items. But when I access the Community, collection or item statistics in the JSPUI view it does not show any value to me.

[image]

Any help ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a fresh installation I strongly suggest to use a more recent version. My recommendation is to use dspace 5.10 
https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/releases/tag/dspace-5.10

that is the best one in terms of stability, otherwise you can try dspace 6.3
Anyway, the latest version of the 4.x series is the 4.9 https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/releases/tag/dspace-4.9

The issues is probably due to issue in the SOLR statistics core but without additional information, logs file, is difficult to guess. Take a look to what is logged in the ${dspace.dir}/log/dspace.log ${dspace.dir}/log/solr.log when you access the statistics page